# Is there a quick way to check for nil args in a Clojure function?

Tags: clojure, null

In Phil Hagelberg's ([technomancy](https://twitter.com/technomancy)) [gripes file](https://github.com/technomancy/dotfiles/blob/master/.gripes.org) he states the following about Clojure:

> nil is everywhere and causes bugs that are difficult to find the source

Now Phil is a smart guy who has contributed a lot to the Clojure community, and everyone uses his stuff - so I thought this was worth pondering for a moment.

One easy way to manage nil args to a function is to throw an error:

```
(defn myfunc [myarg1]
  (when (nil? myarg1) 
    (throw (Exception. "nil arg for myfunc")))
  (prn "done!"))
```

These two extra lines per argument reek of boilerplate. Is there an idiomatic way to remove them via metadata or macros?

My question is **Is there a quick way to check for nil args in a Clojure function?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a clojure language based solution for these situations:
http://clojure.org/special_forms#toc10

```
(defn constrained-sqr [x]
    {:pre  [(pos? x)]
     :post [(> % 16), (< % 225)]}
    (* x x))
```

Adapted to your requirements:

```
(defn constrained-fn [ x]
  {:pre  [(not (nil? x))]}
  x)
(constrained-fn nil)
=> AssertionError Assert failed: (not (nil? x))  ...../constrained-fn (form-init5503436370123861447.clj:1)
```

**And there is also the @fogus contrib library [core.contracts](https://github.com/clojure/core.contracts), a more sophisticated tool**

More info on this page http://blog.fogus.me/2009/12/21/clojures-pre-and-post/

Comment: When clojure 1.6 comes around, you can replace (not (nil? x)) for some?

Comment: @dAni it seems you are right as i can read on  the clojure 1.6 changes https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/changes.md#23-new-some-operations

Comment: `{:pre  [(not (nil? x))]}` can be reduced to `{:pre [x]}`