# Clojure assert not nil at compile time?

Tags: macros, clojure, compile-time

We can see in Clojure [a way to use design by contract to check that arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22222458/15441) to a function in Clojure are not-nil at runtime.

```
(defn constrained-fn [ x]
  {:pre  [(not (nil? x))]}
  x)
(constrained-fn nil)
=> AssertionError Assert failed: (not (nil? x))  ...../constrained-fn (form-init5503436370123861447.clj:1)
```

We can see a way to [check the type of an expression at compile time](http://clojurefun.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/macro-magic-typeof-and-primitive-2/) in Clojure

```
(defmacro typeof 
  ([expression]
    (:class (expression-info expression)))

(defmacro primitive? 
  ([expression]
    (:primitive? (expression-info expression))))
```

Here is my take on the question based on [compile-time macros in Clojure](http://java.dzone.com/articles/macro-lifecycle-clojure):

```
(defmacro compile-time-nil-check [x] (assert (not (nil? x))))
(def my-nullable nil)
(compile-time-nil-check my-nullable)
```

My question is - **is there a way to check that a 'constant' is not nil at compile time in Clojure?**

(I realise this question might seem trivial- I want to use it as a building block for a subsequent question about compile-time type checks in Clojure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by 'constant' you mean something stored in a global `var`

```
(def my-nullable nil)
```

that can be resolved at compile-time, then:

```
(defmacro compile-time-var-nil-check [x] 
  (let [x @(resolve x)] 
    (assert (not (nil? x)))))
```