# A less cumbersome pattern for checking function parameters for nil in Clojure without throwing an assertion?

Tags: clojure

This was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221645/is-there-a-quick-way-to-check-for-nil-args-in-a-clojure-function), but the answers are all unacceptable.

I'm trying to apply some defensive programming techniques to clojure and I'm finding some things cumbersome.

Like checking function parameters:

```
(defn my-tolower [s]
  (if (nil? s) nil
               (.toLowerCase s)
               ))
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

I'm aware of `:pre`, but that throws an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `nil` is falsey you could use `when`:

```
(when s (.toLowerCase s))
```

if you want the test you could use `some?` instead of `nil?`:

```
(if (some? s) (.toLowerCase s))
```

Comment: Just remember booleans: `false` is also falsey. If the argument is supposed to be a boolean -- both `true` and `false` are acceptable values, but `nil` isn't -- you may need to be verbose and explicit and use `nil?` or `false?`.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you simply want `some->`, no?

```
(defn my-tolower [s]
  (some-> s .toLowerCase))

(my-tolower "HELLO") => "hello"
(my-tolower     nil) => nil
```

or just inline it without the wrapper function:

```
(some-> "HELLO" .toLowerCase)   => "hello"
(some->  nil    .toLowerCase)   => nil
```

Answer (score 1):

there are other aproaches too:

**fnil**, probably what I'd do

```
clojure.core/fnil
([f x] [f x y] [f x y z])
  Takes a function f, and returns a function that calls f, replacing
  a nil first argument to f with the supplied value x. Higher arity
  versions can replace arguments in the second and third
  positions (y, z). Note that the function f can take any number of
  arguments, not just the one(s) being nil-patched.
```

provide a default value for a nil accepting fn. /

```
(let [f (fnil str/lower-case "")]
  (f nil))
""
```

or catching the NPE

```
(let [f str/lower-case] 
  (try (f nil) 
    (catch NullPointerException ne nil)))
""
```

or just `str`

```
(.toLowerCase (str nil))
""
```

alternativly `defprotocol` and `extend-protocol` for nil maybe